# Set stacking column graph colors from the bottom up

Tags: highcharts

How to change the order of colors in a stacking column graph from the bottom up? Default colors come from the top down.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you talking about which color is used for which series? The order the series appear in the legend? The order in which columns will stack?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pnr6r3dd/ I want the green color was at the bottom of the graph. The number of charts may vary, and the colors always start from the top down. I want to color started from the bottom

Comment: What is it that prevents you from just ordering the colors-array in reverse?

Comment: Well, again - you need to clarify whether you're talking about JUST the color, or if you mean the series that is green should be at the bottom. See my answer for examples of both scenarios...

Comment: does this problem solved? @lgor? I have the same question here. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If you mean the stacking order of the series, you can set the `index` property for each series.

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/zhr142jy/

If you mean that you just want the colors in a different order, you can define the colors array yourself:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/zhr142jy/2/

If you mean something else, add more detail to your question to clarify.